# React search with pagination without double setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, state

I'm implementing search with pagination in React. So far I found few examples of it, but all they use code with double `setState()`, before and after AJAX call to backend. For example my current solution is:

```js
import React from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"

import SearchField from "components/SearchField"
import SearchResults from "components/SearchResults"

import Item from "models/Item"

class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      query: "",
      page: 1,
      foundItems: []
    }
    this.handleSearch = this.handleSearch.bind(this)
    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this)
  }

  updateSearchResults() {
    const query = this.state.query
    const params = {
      page: this.state.page
    }
    Item.search(query, params).then((foundItems) => {
      this.setState({ foundItems })
    })
  }

  handleSearch(event) {
    this.setState({
      query: event.target.value
    }, this.updateSearchResults)
  }

  handlePageChange(data) {
    this.setState({
      page: data.selected + 1
    }, this.updateSearchResults)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <SearchField onSearch={this.handleSearch} />
        <SearchResults
            onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
            onSelect={this.props.onSelect}
            items={this.state.foundItems}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Search.propTypes = {
  onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

export default Search
```

I know that I can change interface of `updateSearchResults` to receive query and page as arguments and then I can avoid first `setState` to pass values there, but it doesn't look like a good solution, because when list of search parameters will grow (sorting order, page size, filters for example) then it'll get a bit clumsy. Plus I don't like idea of manual state pre-management in `handleSearch` and `handlePageChange` functions in this way. I'm looking for a better implementation.

Comment: Do you mean you only want to call setState once, instead of multiple times?

Comment: Also, why does your query object need to be part of the state - why cant you store it in a non state variable?

Comment: @Alex yes, I want to call `setState` once, because I don't like that it can make application slow, potentially. not in this case, but I just was asking for a good practic

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully sure what you are asking, but you can optimise your code a bit by doing the following:

```
class Search extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.page = 1;
    this.query = "";
    this.state = {
      foundItems: []
    }
    this.handlePageChange = this.handlePageChange.bind(this)
  }

  updateSearchResults(event) {    
   if(typeof event === "object")
      this.query = event.target.value;

    const params = {
      page: this.page
    }
    Item.search(this.query, params).then((foundItems) => {
      this.setState({ foundItems })
    })
  }

  handlePageChange(data) {    
    this.page = data.selected + 1;
    this.updateSearchResults();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search">
        <SearchField onSearch={this.updateSearchResults} />
        <SearchResults
            onPageChange={this.handlePageChange}
            onSelect={this.props.onSelect}
            items={this.state.foundItems}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it strange to have 2 places to put your state in? It seems that in this case we use `this.state` and `this.` as two containers for same stuff

Comment: This.whatever is not state. Only this.state is a state variable. The rest are just global variables